# To check or not to check (to Nothing(null))?

Tags: .net, performance

From the **performance** view, is it better to check or not to check for Nothing(null) before set it?

Is clear that for readability maybe there is no need of supplementary step, but for performance? Maybe testing the IF is less time consuming that setting to NULL, if there is no need of?!

I run that on a computer, and the result was the same.

```
  Dim sw As New Stopwatch()

  sw.Start()
  For i As Integer = 0 To 10000
    _MyObject = Nothing
  Next

  sw.Stop()
  Console.WriteLine("no check: {0}", sw.Elapsed)
  sw.Reset()

  sw.Start()
  For i As Integer = 0 To 10000
    If _MyObject IsNot Nothing Then
      _MyObject = Nothing
    End If
  Next

  sw.Stop()
  Console.WriteLine("with check: {0}", sw.Elapsed)
```

Result:

> no check: 00:00:00.00003**26**
>   with check: 00:00:00.00003**49**

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really is no logical reason to check if the value is already null/Nothing. As you can see you take a small hit in performance with the check anyway.

Comment: I think one of us misunderstood the question. The OP was always going to set the object to null. The if was to avoid setting it to null, if it was null already.

Comment: @Moron, @serhio - Oh boy, I am very sure that I misread the question. I assumed this was a more general question about null checking.

Answer (score 1):

```
  If _MyCustomObject IsNot Nothing Then
      _MyCustomObject = Nothing
```

My guess is that there is really no difference between the two. If there is one, it will be negligible (micro-optimization). (And like I said in my comment the if statement is most likely slower).  And this one is more verbose.  You don't care if it is nothing, you just need it to be nothing when you're done.  You're adding an extra step where you don't need it. Less code to read normally means it's clearer to the reader and that = better in my book.

There will be times you want to check before setting a value.  Say if you have to retrieve the value from a database, but this most likely isn't one of them.

Comment: I mean, maybe testing the IF is less time consuming that setting to NULL, if there is no need.

Comment: I can see what you're saying, but in this instance even if there is a perfomance gain, it will be microscopic.  It'll be a micro-optimization.

Comment: So, I'd like to understand if is a gain, even microscopic :)

Comment: I'd have to double check to be sure, but I am almost positive that it's not.  You are checking to see if the variable points to a reference.  That will most likely take as much or more time, than just setting it to null outright.  I would almost guess that it will take longer to check and then set it.  So you're probably paying a penalty when it's not null, than optimizing it when it is.

Comment: This is of course assuming that the if statement isn't optimized away by the compiler :)

Comment: With an optimizing compiler, it's usually not worth reasoning about what will be "faster" at the source code level. Take a look at what the compiler spits out to be executed if you're interested in what's actually faster.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your stopwatch times come out to be the same is because you're not resetting the stopwatch in between rounds.  StartNew() won't work.  The sw.Elapsed from your second run is reporting the same time as your first run.

Replace sw.StartNew() with a restart:

```
sw.Restart()
```

When I run it on my machine, I get .248 and .592 respectively.

Adding If statements is always slower from a performance perspective. But, from a best practices standpoint, you should always check to see if an object is null before using it.

Comment: often if the object is null I throw exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to set it to null, then just set it. The code is more readable that way.

Having an extra if might have perf implications too, but the compiler might be smart enough to optmize it out, so your tests might not be able to tell the difference.

So just setting it to null has two upsides

- Readability (the more important one)
- Possibly better perf because of the missing if.

A possible upside for doing the not-null check is that .net engine *might* run some extra code about objects going out of scope when you set stuff to null. I don't think that is good enough reason for sacrificing readability, though.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, on modern CPUs it's better to always do some small operation than to check and then do it only if it's necessary. This is because the branch instruction can break the pipeline in the CPU, causing a significant (several cycles) delay. If you always do the small operation, not only is there no time spent doing a comparison, there is also no chance of stalling the pipeline.

In other words, there's almost no way that checking is going to make things faster, and could possibly slow things down. Odds are that the JIT optimizer removes the `If` anyway, though.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be surprised the compiler removes the if test and generates the exact same IL for both. But you could run ilasm on your resulting assembly to know for sure.

Comment: Interesting. Did you try both debug and release (optimized) builds?